# Logrotation has different behaviors when reading from "/etc/logrotate.conf" and "/etc/logrotate.d/*conf" files

Tags: configuration, log, logrotate

We need to keep only one log file of each service in our Ubuntu 20.04 servers. I've modified the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file as follows:

```
weekly
su root adm
rotate 0
create
ifempty
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

And for a specific service, think of `misc` for example, which makes the `vmware-network.log` log files, I have a config file in `/etc/logrotate.d/misc` which is as follows:

```
/var/log/vmware-network.*.log {
  su root root
  rotate 0
  daily
  missingok
  ifempty
}
```

Now when I test my logrotation with `logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.conf`, it doesn't delete any of `vmware-network.*.log` files, it just makes them zero in size. However when I use `logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.d/misc`, it keeps only one `vmware-network.log` file and deletes other numbered log files.

`logrotate` doesn't do my desired job since it is reading from the default config file `/etc/logrotate.conf`. I want to know what is making this difference between these two config files and how to resolve it.

**P.S:**

1. All other config files of `/etc/logrotate.d/` have the same behavior. they will keep one log file when forced to read from them. I only mentioned `misc` here because it has many `vmware-network.log` files and I can easily see the difference it makes.
2. The permissions and user/groups of mentioned log files and `/var/log` are:

   ```
   -rw-------  1 root   root   vmware-network.log  
   drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog   /var/log/
   ```
3. I've tried different approaches with different configurations, but none of each worked. I've also added `misc` logrotation config into the `logrotate.conf` and executed it, but the output was still the same.
4. One common error I've run into was:

   ```
   error: skipping "/var/log/vmware-network.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
   ```

   And I set different `su` directives for different config files, e.g `su root adm` for `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`. Although it didn't send me the error, still not doing the job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem on my own servers (Ubuntu 20.04), and I found out you should remove `create` directive from the main config file meaning `/etc/logrotate.conf` and add it ( if needed ) in sub-config files existing in `/etc/logrotate.d/<CONFIG_FILE>`.

Even though it appears that this approach resolves your issue, I don't exactly know what's the reason behind it so I cannot give you reference-based reasons. I've found this by trial and error.